# Guardar Ñ con cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp

tengo mi proyecto bajo cakephp 3 y al momento de guardar textos con la letra ñ me muestra un carácter especial por ejemplo algo así

**Los niños juegan**

cuando reviso en la BD esta así

**los ni?os juegan**

he revisado la configuración del proyecto en el archivo /config/app.php dentro de las siguientes secciones:

```
'App' => [
       'encoding' => env('APP_ENCODING', 'UTF-8'),
       'defaultLocale' => env('APP_DEFAULT_LOCALE', 'es_PE'),
 ]
'Datasources' => [
    'default' => [
           'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
        'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'database' => 'mybasededatos',
        'encoding' => 'utf8',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'flags' => [],
        'cacheMetadata' => true,
        'log' => false,

        'quoteIdentifiers' => false,

        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL', null),
   ]
 ]
```

según leo así debería estar, no se si algo me este faltando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Todo lo que uses debe estar en UTF-8**: Servidor de aplicaciones, el php, tus html, la codificación de tus archivos o del IDE que uses, la colación de la base de datos, la conexión hacia la base de datos. Incluso APIs o frameworks que uses. Si se te pasa algo de eso es cuando aparecen los caracteres extraños. Mira este [post](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24705/problemas-con-inserciones-de-letra-%C3%91-y-acentos-en-sql-server-desde-php/24710#24710)

Answer (score 0):

en tu base de datos, específicamente donde guardas esta información, debes establecer la codificación de caracteres (Character Set) en UTF8 y la Collation utf8_spanish2_ci, la he usado en múltiples proyectos y me ha servido. Espero que esta respuesta te sea útil.