# Consulta sobre expresión regular php solo letras, espacio, acentos, tildes

Tags: php, regex

Tengo una expresión regular la cual quiero que acepte letras, espacio, acentos, tildes, ñ, ect. Pero no me funciona.

¿Alguien sabe como hacer la expresión regular?

Así esta la expresión regular

```
"/^[[:alnum:][:space:]]+$/"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con esto: `[a-zA-Z áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑ]`

Comment: me funciona cuando escribo una palabra yo, pero cuando la palabra viene de la base de datos no funciona sabes que puede ser

Comment: Si, no se que lenguaje uses, ni base de datos pero me parece que tienes problemas de codificación de caracteres.

Comment: hay me funciona aplique utf8_encode a la palabra gracias.

Comment: Aun así, tienes mal la codificación de caracteres, con un buena configuración en utf8 de las partes que integran tu sistema no deberías usar ese tipo de funciones: Mira mi repuesta en este post: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24705/problemas-con-inserciones-de-letra-%C3%91-y-acentos-en-sql-server-desde-php/24710#24710