# Problema con acentos al compilar HTML en R-Markdown

Tags: html, r, gráficas, markdown

tengo el siguiente problema:

Al crear una gráfica, trabajando desde R-Markdown, y al cambiar el título y en este se incluye un carácter especial como acentos, ñ, etc. tengo que cambiar el `enconding` y coloco la siguiente instrucción: `Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", 'en_US.UTF-8')` y acepta los caracteres especiales al correr el `chunk` donde esta la gráfica aparece de la manera esperada, por ejemplo:

[image: Imagen esperada]

Pero al compilar el HTML mediante knit, obtengo lo siguiente:

[image: Imagen error]

Esto sucede usando ggplot, gráficas de R base y otras gráficas proporcionadas por otras librerías.

¿Cómo puedo arreglar este issue?

Comment: Revisa el encoding del script Rmd. Si usas Rstudio, puedes hacer `File -> Save with encoding` y selecciona UTF-8

Comment: Aún guardando con UTF-8 no hay cambio al compilar con knitr el HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Todo lo que uses debe estar en UTF-8**: Servidor de aplicaciones, el php o java o lo que uses, tus html, la codificación de tus archivos o del IDE que uses, la colación de la base de datos, la conexión hacia la base de datos. Incluso APIs o frameworks que uses. Si se te pasa algo de eso es cuando aparecen los caracteres extraños. [Mira este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24705/problemas-con-inserciones-de-letra-%C3%91-y-acentos-en-sql-server-desde-php/24710#24710).

Comment: Te sugiero no agregar respuestas repetidas, mejor enlaza a la pregunta que tiene solución ya que esta respuesta la has agregado anteriormente. Revisar [answer].

Comment: No ves el link?? Ahi esta la solución  Jorgesys

Answer (score 1):

El problema se soluciono como menciono **abrahamhs**; especificamente escribiendo directamente en la consola de `R` (o desde `RStudio`) `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", 'en_US.UTF-8’)` y `Sys.setenv(LANGUAGE="en")`

El último código, puede cambiarse por: `Sys.setenv(LANGUAGE="es")`

Yo estoy trabajando sobre macOS High Sierra y si se quiere cambiar ajustes en la consola sobre la geolocalización, se puede ver la siguiente [liga](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165108/in-os-x-lion-lang-is-not-set-to-utf-8-how-to-fix-it).

Answer (score 0):

Me ocurria lo mismo, lo que tienes que hacer es guardar tu archivo como formato UTF-8, en r-Studio cuando guardes tu script le picas en la pestañita de FILE es la primera y en la opción aproximadamente 12 "**Save with encoding...**" le picas y te aparecerá la siguiente ventana:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

das clic en UTF-8 o en windows-1252 alguna de esas 2 te debe funcionar!

Saludos!