# Sacar tildes de una cadena en C#

Tags: c#

He buscado pero no encuentro lo que necesito, si bien encuentro soluciones para reemplazar pero no logro dar con una solución que me ayude.

Tengo una cadena de entrada con tildes y necesito sacar las tildes, mi código:

```
string palabra = "pálábrá cón tíldés";

string palabaSinTilde = Regex.Replace(palabra, @"[^0-9A-Za-z]", "",
RegexOptions.None);
```

La salida que tengo es: `"plbr cn tlds"`

Lo que yo necesito: palabra con tildes

Gracias, que tengan una buena tarde.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

Sinceramente con esto lo solucione:

```
string palabaConTildes = "áéíóúñ";

string palabaSinTildes = Regex.Replace(palabaConTildes.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD), @"[^a-zA-z0-9 ]+", "");
```

y la variable que lleva por nombre *palabaSinTildes* queda de la siguiente forma: **aeioun**

Comment: No agregues otra respuesta (y menos cuando la aceptada es la tuya). Si tenes algo que agregar, agregalo en la respuesta que ya te diste.

Answer (score 16):

Prueba con el siguiente método de extensión

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string SinTildes(this string texto) =>
        new String(
            texto.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD)
            .Where(c => CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c) != UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark)
            .ToArray()
        )
        .Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormC);
}
```

Explicación:

Los caracteres como `á`, `ö`, etc puedes ser expresados en Unicode de dos formas: Un sólo caracter que corresponde al caractér ya acentuado : `á` por ejemplo o dos caracteres consecutivos donde el primer caracter es la tilde y el siguiente el caracter al cual se va a aplicar `´a`. Ambas formas resultan para los editores de texto en mostrar esta versión -> `á`

Esta línea:

```
.texto.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD)
```

Asegura que la cadena se expanda a separa los caracterés como tides y otros modificadores en sus caracteres consitutyentes.

Luego

```
.Where(c => CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c) != UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark)
```

Se asegura de quedarnos con solo aquellos caracteres que no sea diacríticos.

Luego se crea una nueva cadena con caracteres ya removidos

```
 new String(...)
```

Finalmente se regresa la cadena a su estado normal con esta línea

```
.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormC)
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, intenté aplicar tu solución pero no pude utilizarla, debe ser porque estoy utilizando VS2008, se me olvidó indicar ese gran detalle, pero si ya encontre la solución.

Comment: Bueno el código es muy fácil de convertir a versiones antiguas de C#. Si deseas lo puedo agregar

Comment: Gracias Carlos, ya lo solucioné :D

Comment: Ojo, este codigo elimina todos los caracteres diacriticos (Incluyendo Ñ)

Comment: El símbolo de la verguililla: ~ También se conoce como tilde, por lo que tiene sentido quitársela a la ñ. Además si ves el regex de la pregunta tampoco incluiría la ñ.

Answer (score 3):

Ya solucioné mi problema,
Primero averigue el formato de mi archivo, en este caso era UTF8, ya con ese dato encontre la solución:

```
string accentedStr;
byte[] tempBytes;
tempBytes = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(“ISO-8859- 8”).GetBytes(accentedStr);
string asciiStr = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(tempBytes);
```

Comment: En realidad lo hiciste funcionar, pero no solucionaste el problema. Para corregirlo no importando los lenguajes que uses: Todo debe estar en UTF-8: Servidor de aplicaciones, el php o java o lo que uses, tus html, la codificación de tus archivos o del IDE que uses, la colación de la base de datos, la conexión hacia la base de datos. Incluso APIs o frameworks que uses. Si se te pasa algo de eso es cuando aparecen los caracteres extraños. Mira este hilo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24705/problemas-con-inserciones-de-letra-%C3%91-y-acentos-en-sql-server-desde-php/24710#24710

Answer (score 1):

Algo así

```
string textoOriginal = "Mañana será otro día"

string textoNormalizado = textoOriginal.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD)
Regex reg = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]");
string textoSinAcentos = reg.Replace(textoNormalizado, "");
Debug.WriteLine(textoSinAcentos);
```

Answer (score 0):

creo que esto es lo que buscas:

```
 string textoOriginal = "Mañana será otro día";//transformación UNICODE
 string textoNormalizado = textoOriginal.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);
//coincide todo lo que no sean letras y números ascii o espacio
//y lo reemplazamos por una cadena vacía.Regex reg = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9]");
string textoSinAcentos = reg.Replace(textoNormalizado, "");
Debug.WriteLine(textoSinAcentos); //muestra 'Manana sera otro dia'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string textoOriginal = "Mañana será otro día";
string[] nombreLargo = textoOriginal.Split(' ');
string name = "";
foreach (var xs in nombreLargo)
{
  string textoNombre = xs.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);
  string text= reg.Replace(textoNombre, "");
  name = name + txt+" ";
}
```

//Resultado es name

Comment: Hola. Podrías agregar un poco de información acerca de lo que hace tu código?

Comment: Buenas. En realidad hace lo mismo de quitar las ñ y acentos, pero considerando el espacio, porque hay casos en que te lo une la cadena y el resultado no debería ser ese.

Comment: Bueno disculpa falto esta declaración al código. Regex reg = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9]");