# Errores de acentuación en aplicación web Angular + NodeJS + MySQL

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, angular, apache2

Buen día, estoy desarrollando una aplicación en la cuál el Front-end está desarrollado en Angular 6, el Back-end está desarrollado en NodeJS (10.13.0) y la base de datos es MySQL. El flujo de ejecución normal es que se accede a la aplicación web y se cargan determinados textos desde base de datos, no obstante cuando se visualiza en el front, tiene problemas para mostrar las palabras que usan tilde, por ejemplo:

Agronomía se muestra como AgronomÃ­a.

He estado trazando una ruta de dónde puede estar el error y supongo que ha de estar en la codificación de los datos MySQL y las colaciones, sin embargo cuando revisé la base de datos me encontré con que los `character set` estaban definidos así:

```
mysql> show variables like 'char%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | latin1                     |
| character_set_connection | latin1                     |
| character_set_database   | latin1                     |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | latin1                     |
| character_set_server     | latin1                     |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
```

Y las colaciones están definidas así:

```
mysql> show variables like '%collation%';
+----------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name        | Value              |
+----------------------+--------------------+
| collation_connection | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_database   | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_server     | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
+----------------------+--------------------+
```

Y cuando ejecuto una consulta como: `SELECT * FROM tabla;`

La respuesta de Agronomía es: `Agronomía`.

Sin embargo cuando llega al Front, llega como: `AgronomÃ­a`.

Quizás el problema esté en la codificación de las colaciones vs las codificaciones de los character_set's. Sin embargo si pongo cada variable del character_set en codificación `utf8` o incluso `utf8mb4` la respuesta a la consulta es `AgronomÃ­a`.

También he intentado cambiando la codificación que usa el servidor apache, añadiendo al final del archivo `apache2.conf` la línea `AddDefaultCharset utf-8`, sin embargo esto no funciona. También revisé la codificación del archivo *.html* que genera el CLI de Angular, pero también parece estar correcto cuando la codificación dice `utf-8`.

No sé dónde más debería revisar o qué me falta por configurar o si la base de datos está con los character_set's y collations correctos. Agradezco cualquier ayuda, gracias por la atención prestada.

Comment: Agregaste en el header el lang?

Answer (score 0):

La colación de tu base de datos debe ser `utf8_spanish_ci`. En las ultimas versiones de mysql modificaron la colación por defecto a `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` y tuve que mover el `my.ini`:

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8
[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8
[mysqld]
collation-server = utf8_spanish_ci
character-set-server = utf8
```

También en tus html tienes que agregar el meta:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

En resumen [todo tiene que estar en utf8](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24705/problemas-con-inserciones-de-letra-%C3%91-y-acentos-en-sql-server-desde-php/24710#24710).

Answer (score 0):

Te aconsejo primero ver con el inspector de elementos en la pestaña de red como te esta llegando la respuesta de esos datos, si llega bien queda descartado tu backend.

Tambien asegurate que tengo los siguiente el index de proyecto angular:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
```