# Usar UTF8 en método POST de PHP

Tags: php

Tengo un humilde formulario de contacto montado en mi sitio, funciona que es lo importante, pero no logro que me reconozca los caracteres especiales introducidos como acentos o la letra Ñ.

Entiendo que es por el cotejamiento, estuve revisando en foros y el sitio oficial de PHP sobre el uso de [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/es/function.htmlentities.php) y [html_entity_decode](http://php.net/manual/es/function.html-entity-decode.php) pero no encontré ejemplos prácticos o términos menos técnicos.

Este es el documento en PHP que realiza el envío, a lo mejor debo cambiar este metodo cuando recibo los datos de POST

```
<?php

if(empty($_POST['name'])        ||
   empty($_POST['email'])       ||
   empty($_POST['phone'])       ||
   empty($_POST['message']) ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
    echo "!Ningún argumento proporcionado!";
    return false;
   }

$name = strip_tags(html_entity_decode($_POST['name']));
$email_address = strip_tags(html_entity_decode($_POST['email']));
$phone = strip_tags(html_entity_decode($_POST['phone']));
$message = strip_tags(html_entity_decode($_POST['message']));


$to = 'ejemplo@mail.com'; 
$email_subject = "Asunto";
$email_body = "Tiene un nuevo mensaje";
$headers = "From: noreply@mail.com\n"; 
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;
?>
```

El formulario es simple HTML y lo valido con JavaScript, no creo que esté ahí el error, pero si lo solicitan con todo el gusto.

!Muchas gracias y Bendiciones!

---

Este es el formulario en HTML

```
<form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate="novalidate">
  <div class="control-group">
    <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls mb-0 pb-2">
      <label>Nombre</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="name" type="text" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Por favor ingrese su nombre.">
      <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls mb-0 pb-2">
      <label>Correo Eletrónico</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="email" type="email" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Por favor ingrese su email.">
      <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls mb-0 pb-2">
      <label>Teléfono</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="phone" type="tel" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Por favor ingrese un número telefónico.">
      <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls mb-0 pb-2">
      <label>Mensaje</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="message" rows="5" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Por favor ingrese su mensaje."></textarea>
      <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div id="success"></div>
  <div class="form-group mb-5">
    <button type="submit" class="btn primary_color" id="sendMessageButton">Enviar&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="material-icons" style="vertical-align: middle;"> send </i></button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Nota: En mi cabecera tengo definido

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
```

Este es el JS con el que envío los datos a PHP

```
$(function() {

  $("#contactForm input,#contactForm textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({
    preventSubmit: true,
    submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
      // additional error messages or events
    },
    submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
      event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
      // get values from FORM
      var name = $("input#name").val();
      var email = $("input#email").val();
      var phone = $("input#phone").val();
      var message = $("textarea#message").val();
      var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
      // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
      if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
        firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
      }
      $this = $("#sendMessageButton");
      $this.prop("disabled", true); // Disable submit button until AJAX call is complete to prevent duplicate messages
      $.ajax({
        url: "./mail/contact_me.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
          name: name,
          phone: phone,
          email: email,
          message: message
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function() {
          // Success message
          $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
          $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
            .append("</button>");
          $('#success > .alert-success')
            .append("<strong>Su mensaje fue enviado exitosamente.</strong>");
          $('#success > .alert-success')
            .append('</div>');
          //clear all fields
          $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
        },
        error: function() {
          // Fail message
          $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
          $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
            .append("</button>");
          $('#success > .alert-danger').append($("<strong>").text("Lo sentimos " + firstName + ", el servidor no responde en este momento. Por favor intente más tarde"));
          $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
          //clear all fields
          $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
        },
        complete: function() {
          setTimeout(function() {
            $this.prop("disabled", false); // Re-enable submit button when AJAX call is complete
          }, 1000);
        }
      });
    },
    filter: function() {
      return $(this).is(":visible");
    },
  });

  $("a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab("show");
  });
});

/*When clicking on Full hide fail/success boxes */
$('#name').focus(function() {
  $('#success').html('');
});
```

Aclaro que también estoy usando jqBootstrapValidation: https://reactiveraven.github.io/jqBootstrapValidation/

Comment: ¿Podrías subir el **HTML** de tu página de contacto? Eso facilitaría mucho las cosas.

Comment: @PHPMyguel Claro que sí, ya mismo lo edito

Comment: Estoy viendo que no envías la información del formulario a través de su **action** ¿De qué manera estás enviando los datos al **.php**? Necesitaría ver la función con la que le pasas los datos por POST.

Comment: La envío también con otro archivo JS, ya mismo lo agrego al código inicial

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24705/problemas-con-inserciones-de-letra-%C3%91-y-acentos-en-sql-server-desde-php/24710#24710

Comment: Parece estar claro que el problema lo tienes en el lado del servidor, seguramente en la configuración de tu servidor Web. Podrías de todas formas forzar el UTF-8 en la creación de la llamada AJAX añadiéndole **scriptCharset: "utf-8"**

Comment: Gracias por sus amables observaciones, voy a comunicarme con soporte de mi hosting a ver que respuesta me pueden ofrecer y les cuento. Gracias

Answer (score 2):

cómo tienes declarado el charset de tu página?

Fijate si lo tienes así:

```html
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
```

Porque esto define cómo se codifica la página para lo que son las tildes,y es en base a esto que se deberían pasan las variables a tu formulario en php

.....

Busqué y encontré que para usar html_entity_decode tiene una sintaxis:

```
html_entity_decode(string,flags,character-set)
```

la parte del string es tu variable, las flags corresponde a si quieres transformar dobles comillas pero no es tu caso, y el character-set creo que es lo que te falta, prueba con esto:

```
$name = strip_tags(html_entity_decode($_POST['name'], ENT_NOQUOTES, "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: Gracias Sebastian por tu apoyo, sí, mi página `contacto.html` tiene declarada esa etiqueta meta en la cabecera. Creo que mi error está en el método POST y la codificación con la que convierto esos datos

Comment: Probé tu código pero no funciona Sebastian, es muy triste pues me parecía que por allí era el problema