# Chrome mobile no interpreta mi pdf generado

Tags: android, pdf

Tengo una aplicación que genera un fichero pdf en linea, este funciona correctamente en todos los exploradores en versiones para pc, y en los sistemas iOS también, pero en algunas versiones de Android muestra una pagina llena de códigos raros, como si no pudiera interpretar el pdf.

Tengo lector de pdf instalado, incluso puedo descargar otros pdfs, pero el generado desde mi página no.

[image: Pantallazo de la tablet]

```html
byte[] data = wsnc.getNomina(tipoNomina, dni2, dup, fecha, cdCasnm, cdCierre, cdHabil, cdCalculo, cd);
    
    if (data == null) {
                //System.out.println("Nomina mal generada por causas externas a la Intranet");
                response.setContentType("text/html");
                PrintWriter pdf = response.getWriter();
                pdf.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
                pdf.println("alert('Ha sido imposible obtener la nomina solicitada.');");
                pdf.println("history.back();");
                pdf.println("</script>");
                pdf.close();
              }
              else {
       response.reset();
       //response.setContentType("application/x-download");
       //response.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
                response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"Nomina-" + dni2 + "-" + fecha + "-" + tipoNomina + "-" + ".pdf\"");    
    response.setContentType("application/x-download;charset=UTF-8");
    
                response.getOutputStream().write(data);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Lorena 
Un Saludo

Comment: Bienvenida a StackOverflow! Me temo que sin ningún tipo de código o error no creo que la comunidad pueda ayudarte mucho. Te recomiendo aunque sea adjuntar una muestra de esos "códigos raros" que se te generan en tu pagina. Un saludo :)

Comment: gracias, modificado¡¡

Comment: Verifica que el servidor responde con una cabecera Content-Type: application/pdf.

Comment: he añadido los fuentes que generan el pdf

Comment: @Lorena que tipo de servidor estas usando, usas cPanel ? para dar una respuesta más completa?

Comment: Prueba response.setContentType("application/pdf;charset=UTF-8");

Comment: Tu modificación para poner código quedo igual de mal, debes de poner el código de los componentes involucrados pero no 3 lineas. Ademas el código no debe ser imagen.

Comment: El problema es la codificación de caracteres, pero con tan poco código es imposible saber donde esta mal. La codificación de caracteres se define en muchos lados.Debes de tener una codificación donde no aparezcan diamantes.

Comment: @ordago tb lo he probado, sin resultados.

Comment: @Jorgesys el codigo pertenece a una jsp de un gestor de contenidos (opencms)

Comment: @abrahamhs si funciona en unos moviles y en otros no, con la misma version de navegador... crees que puede ser problema del codigo???

Comment: @Lorena funciona en algunos y en otros no? :-| te sugiero agregar más código como indica abrahamhs.

Comment: Tienes problemas de codificación, pero como te comento hay muchas cosas que afectan la codificación. En particular te pasa con los archivos donde tienes el código del PDF o con la programación del PDF. Mira esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/24710/3834

Comment: Que versiones de Android pasa dicho error?, cual es el código completo que genera el pdf?, el generador de pdf es un plugin de un tercero o es propio?

Comment: He añadido más codigo.. pero no hay mucho mas que ver. Los datos me los sirve un webService. Vuelvo a aclarar que es una jsp de un gestor de contenidos (openCMS) bajo Tomcat. Y que en unos moviles funciona y en otros no. La tablet donde estoy probando ahora mismo, que no funciona, es una Samsung Galaxy, con android 7. He probado con todos los navegadores de la tablet y nada...

Comment: En pc, funciona con cualquier navegador. En IOS tb funciona... Se supone que android lleva incorporados los paquetes java, no?

Comment: ¿Podrías descargar el PDF con un navegador y compartirnos su contenido a través de algún servicio como Google Drive, Mega, etc? (hazlo con una "nómina ficticia" para no exponer datos personales). Es probable que hayas enviado algún carácter previo al PDF (como el BOM del código fuente) que hace fallar la detección en el navegador o impida el envío de cabeceras al navegador o cualquier otro motivo similar.

Comment: Creo que puede ser porque "tiponomina", en algunas ocasiones viene con espacios... Igual puedo solucionarlo con el encoding

Comment: Va ser que los espacios no eran el problema. 
@OscarGarcia como puedo ver el fuente de un pdf?? 
No puedo mandaros un pdf de prueba, porque no tengo. Como os he dicho, llamo a un webservice que no es mio, es de otra aplicación.

Comment: Puedes usar una herramienta como `hexdump` para decirnos el valor en hexadecimal de los primeros bytes del archivo.

Comment: @OscarGarcia, he añadido una imagen con la primera parte del codigo hexadecimal. Yo no se interpretarlo. Muchas Gracias por tu ayuda