# Error en la request en Tomcat 9 al usar tildes

Tags: java, java-ee, tomcat, struts

En la migración de un proyecto que funciona correctamente bajo Tomcat 7 a Tomcat 9 estoy recibiendo el error `Invalid character found in the request target` al pasar en la request palabras con tilde.

He modificado el archivo server.xml introduciendo en el conector `URIEncoding="UTF-8"` también he introducido en el mismo la clausula `relaxedQueryChars= áÁéÉíÍóÓúÚ` pero sigo recibiendo el mismo error. No puedo tocar el código en sí del proyecto.

Concretamente el error es:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the request target [/SAB/lupaDemanda.do?filtro=LupaEnt&param1=1&param2=29527&param3=OBSERVACI0xd3N%20ANTIRR0xc1BICA
```

Comment: y si tambien agregas [relaxedPathChars](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/http.html) a tu server.xml

Comment: No, he probado con ambos y muestra el mismo error

Comment: quiza tengas otro [caracter invalido](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547899/which-characters-make-a-url-invalid/13500078#13500078) en tu request ademas de las tildes

Comment: He descartado lo de otro caracter (Por ahora) ya que en la misma pantalla cuando pruebo ese filtro sin tildes funciona bien.

Comment: Al analizar el error parece que no estas codificando bien la URL, el valor correcto seria `OBSERVACI%C3%93N%20ANTIRR%C3%81BICA%0A` y tienes `OBSERVACI0xd3N%20ANTIRR0xc1BICA` como estas consumiendo el servicio.

Comment: Revisa [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/24710/3834), el problema no es de permitir caracteres o no, es problema de codificación.