# No puedo ver los tildes o acentos en datos desde json

Tags: json, flutter

Estoy trabajando en VS Code con el framework Flutter y estoy teniendo un problema al obtener datos desde una API Rest de AWS. En mi aplicación en modo debug y en dispositivos físicos no se muestran las tildes o acentos y en su lugar se muestra una serie de caracteres extraños. Lo extraño es que en Postman y web, al ejecutar la API, los datos sí se muestran bien.

[image: Asi se ven los datos en VS Code]
[image: Asi se ven en el simulador IOS]

```
class RegionRepository {
  Future<List<Region>> getRegions() async {
    Response response =
        await get(Uri.parse('${dotenv.env["ENDPOINT"]}/'));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final List result = jsonDecode(response.body)['body'];
      final List<Region> regionList =
          result.map((e) => Region.fromJson(e)).toList();
      return regionList;
    } else {
      throw Exception(response.reasonPhrase);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: sería útil que muestres el código donde recibes estos datos

Comment: Gracias Jonathan!, he agregado el codigo

Comment: La respuesta esta en que pongas todo en UTF-8, mira este hilo, aunque es de php tiene la respuesta, pon todo en utf-8: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/24710/3834

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reemplaza esta línea:

```
 final List result = jsonDecode(response.body)['body'];
```

por

```
final List result = json.decode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes))['body'];
```

Y no te olvides de importar:

```
import 'dart:convert';
```

Con eso podrás decodificar la data utf-8.

Comment: Gracias Diego!, funcionó de inmediato! un abrazo desde Chile!

Answer (score 1):

En la consulta, intenta agregar un `header` para la peticion para que pueda decodificar los datos:

```
    Future<List<Region>> getRegions() async {
      Response response =
        await get(Uri.parse('${dotenv.env["ENDPOINT"]}/'), headers: {"charset": "UTF-8"});
    
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final List result = jsonDecode(response.body)['body'];
      final List<Region> regionList =
          result.map((e) => Region.fromJson(e)).toList();
      return regionList;
    } else {
      throw Exception(response.reasonPhrase);
    }

  }
```

Comment: Gracias Jonathan!, le agregué el header y aun asi continúo visualizando los caracteres extraños en lugar de acentos o tildes...